# How to save the last Position/Value of a trackbar when closing a form?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `Form1` that sends a line of text to another open application using `AppActivate`.

This line of text is created from dropdowns and textboxes, and is sent to the other app using sendkeys and `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(label1.text)`.

I have a trackbar on a second form hooked to `label1` to control the time amount for sleep value. I have the trackbar value set at 100 so that the user has a default value. When the timer is not long enough, the user can go to the second form and increase the slider value.

My problem is that because I have the trackbar value set at 100 everytime the second form opens it resets to the default 100 setting. How can I have a default 100 setting on the trackbar, but once the value is changed it will be there next time the second form is opened?

Also I want it to go back to 100 when the application is close completely (`form 1` closed).

Comment: Is it important that these are two separate programs? Can't you have two forms within the same application?

Comment: @WSC they are both a part of the same VB program, Form1 has a button that opens Form2. Form1 is small because it sits over the receiving application. I would like to keep the slider on the Settings form (Form2) if possible.

Comment: Ok - you should also read this: [ask]

Comment: @WSC Is something wrong with my question?

Comment: It's not very clear the structure of your application, what you've already tried or any problems you've encountered. That link goes into more detail about what makes a good question. It's very helpful to post your code, even if it's only snippets.

Comment: You can store this value in the Application settings, `User` scope. Save the setting when the app/form closes and reload it when the app is restarted/the form is loaded.

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(label1.text)` will not compile with Option Strict on. `.Sleep` expects an `Integer` or `TimeSpan` not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what controls each form has or what it's job is, but it sounds like you can just pass the current trackbar value from one form to another via the constructor:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Set the default value
         TrackBar.Value = 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Pass the current value of trackbar into Form2 constructor
        Dim form2 As New Form2(TrackBar.Value)
        form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    'You can this wherever you need it now
    Dim _TrackBarValue As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal TrackBarValue As Integer)
        _TrackBarValue = TrackBarValue
    End Sub
End Class
```

Obviously, you need to use the right forms for how your controls are layed out.